# Best Jewish place to live - financially

Tags: geography, parnassah-livelihood

I have seen studies done in the past as to the [best places to retire](http://money.usnews.com/money/retirement/best-places-to-retire) or [best cities for raising a family](http://www.forbes.com/sites/tomvanriper/2014/04/16/the-best-cities-for-raising-a-family-2/). I was wondering if anyone ever did a study comparing housing costs, kosher food costs, Jewish schooling tuition costs, Synagogue membership costs, job availability, and average salaries, to figure where it is the most financially sensible place to raise a Orthodox Jewish family. If this was done can someone perhaps link it to an answer. If not why was this never done?

Comment: Don't really see how this is off-topic since it definitely relates to Judaism inasmuch as the costs are incurred because of halachic practices...?

Comment: I think this is on-topic according to the conclusions here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope/

Comment: I'm undecided for now if it's on or off topic. Assuming that it's on topic. Please edit the question to narrow the scope to U.S., Israel (well, I think that anywhere in Israel is the "best place".) If you're talking about U.S., perhaps, an org. such as UJA may have done such a study. In general, in the U.S., as you know, there aren't that many Orthodox communities. Most are clustered in the Northeast and a bot around the L.A. area with a few other scattered "large" U.S. cities such as Chicago. I think if you Google "U.S. Jewish population breakdown", it may be a good start. Don't use "Siri".

Comment: "Best Places to Live" rankings are very subject and generalized to factors that appeal to the majority of people: education, housing, recreation, culture, transportation, commute, health care, crime, etc.  I don't doubt that such a ranking could be done for Jews, butI think it would be particularly difficult due to the varying degree of observance. Example, would several Jewish Day Schools be sufficient for "education" category or do they have to be yeshivishe? Would having a Jewish Community Center  offering numerous programs and classes count or would the city need a rabbinical school? .....

Comment: .....So, in my opinion, such a ranking would have to be limited to specific denominations and sub-genres of Judaism

Comment: No data, but I suggest Cleveland, Ohio. Lower cost of living then the coasts; kosher butchers, bakeries, and restaurants; synagogues, day schools,an eruv, a yeshiva,several daily minyanim.

Comment: @mike. As stated above, the selection would have to be specific to a particular denomination or sub genre of Judaism. Would Cleveland hold true for Modern  Orthodox Jews as well as Hasidim? MO appear to be employed in a massively wide range of occupations so finding employment would arguably be easier than for Haredim who have much more limited range of job skills. Also in terms of work, many Jews in New York City  have a difficult enough time convincing their bosses to allow them to leave early for Shabbat and to take off Holy Days, would there not be a need for a measurement of tolerance?

Comment: @mike. By the way I was not disagreeing with you but giving an example (work) of how such a list might not be accurate for all Jews.

Comment: in israel see  Nefesh B'Nefesh Community Database http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20684/1857